# How to populate text are on click using vue apex charts dataPointIndex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue, apexcharts

I'm attempting populate a text area  onclick from Apex chart.  In the below code pen you can click on the bar and it generates an alert with the value from the chart.  I would like to get that value and place it on the screen using b-card container instead of the alert.  Should I use double curly braces for data binding instead of getElementById?

```
{{data}}
```

Method that returns data from apex chart

```
getAlertData(event, chartContext, config){
   var data = [];
   data = this.series[0].data[config.dataPointIndex]
   return data
}
```

https://codepen.io/tone373/pen/dyajwpa?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Vue, you should not use `document` interface functions such as `getElementById` if you can avoid it.  Yes, use text interpolation with double curly braces, which is the "Vue way" of doing this.  Your codepen's problem is two-fold

One, you're trying to display `{{data}}` but you have no `data` variable.  The **data option** which looks like

```js
data() {
  return {
   ...
  }
}
```

Returns variables you can directly use in your HTML with `{{}}`. A variable called "data" inside the data option is not a great name choice, but it's up to you...  I would name it maybe "cardText". Then assign the value it should display in your click method, and display this variable in your HTML with the `{{}}` syntax.

```js
  data() {
    return {
      chart: {},        
      series: [],
      chartOptions: {}, 
      cardText: ''
    }
  },

...

  selectBar(event, chartContext, config) {
    this.cardText = this.series[0].data[config.dataPointIndex]
  }
```

```html
<div>{{ cardText }}</div>
```

Second problem, is you're trying to display this data outside of your Vue instance.  Notice how you create the Vue instance with

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    ...
})
```

The `#app` is the element the Vue instance attaches to.  Vue *only* has direct control over code **inside** this element, but you're trying to display `{{data}}` **outside** of it within a `<b-card>` element.  You just need to move this code to be inside of `<div id="app">`

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/KKJxPKo)

I used another `<div>` instead of `<b-card>` because your codepen does not include the library to make b-card work.

I'll add that all the above information can be learned from reading the official [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#template-syntax).  If you haven't read or consulted it, it's very well written and will help you learn the Vue framework better than almost any other resource.